# reuse running process with Java || Scala

Tags: java, scala, process

**main aim** = minimize time of execution process.

Want to create system process with running some programm, and reuse it.

For example

```
command = "/client.exe -ip=127.0.0.1 -port=1234" + somecommand
```

execute it

```
Process(command).lineStream.mkString
```

Result of execution is very slow.

How can I run client.exe **once**, and reuse this process. Just send some new commands every time to the existing process **client.exe**.

Any ideas how to increase speed of execution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is actually interprocess communication and/or remote procedure call. You can use several methods to achieve this. Some of them are:

1. Using REST/HTTP, [spray](http://spray.io/) is probably simplest and best solution for this.
2. Using Akka, [Akka](http://akka.io/) supports remote actors, this means you can spawn an actor on the main process and access it from other processes and send/receive messages.
3. If you are on a *nix system you can use raw sockets.
4. Use a message queue, check [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)

Comment: for the REST == Play. I have a heavy program  which I should use. run like process.

Comment: You should consider play only if you have a complex Web application, if you don't need additional Web features like caching, sessions, template rendering etc. spray fits better

Comment: thanks, I know it. But my main issue connected with how to run some program like process in the best way

Answer (score 1):

if *client.exe* has sequential execution and it is designed to quit after work done, then You can't do much. Executable should be written to handle interprocess communication.

Comment: any examples about  "interprocess communication." ?

Comment: Do You have _client.exe_ source codes and could manage it? Or _client.exe_ is any ordinary executable?

Comment: What i mean is, if You have _client.exe_ sources, fast solution is to make a dll instead of executable and reuse it from scala, in such case dynamic library will be preload in memory and You can reuse it as much as you want.